# Could not find server 'dbo' in sys.servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, subsonic

I have a lot of services which query the database. All of them work fine but one service calling a stored procedure gives me following error:

> Could not find server 'dbo' in
>   sys.servers. Verify that the correct
>   server name was specified. If
>   necessary, execute the stored
>   procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add
>   the server to sys.servers.

I have not idea why all the other stored procedures work fine and this one not...

By the way, I use SubSonic as data access layer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like there is an extra "." (or two) in the mapping - i.e. it is trying to find server.database.schema.object. Check your mapping for stray dots / dubious entries.

Comment: If you have table names that contain periods, you'll also want to check that the name is enclosed in brackets, e.g., dbo.[SubSchema.Table] instead of dbo.SubSchema.Table.

Comment: Thx, apparently some underscores were replaced by dots... no clue as why this happened. Thx.

Answer (score 15):

Please run `select name from sys.servers` from the server which you mentioned as default server in configuration file.

Here in name column values should match with your server names used in the report query.

e.g `serverXXX.databasename.schema.tablename`

serverXXX should be there in the result of `select name from sys.servers` otherwise it gives error as got.

Comment: It should be noted that evidently the name IS case sensitive.  I was using a lower case version of a server name and intellisence picked up everything fine, but when time came for execution, I got the original poster's error. Then I used "select * from sys.servers" and noticed the server name was all caps, so I switched to that, viola! It worked!  +1 for setting me on the right path.

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure that the server name matches what you think it is. If you rename the host that SQL Server is running on, you need to rename the SQL Server, too.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/changing-the-name-of-your-sql-server/192

Answer (score 1):

I had another issue with the same exception so I'll post here if someone stumble upon it:

Be careful if you specify the server name in synonyms. I had a different server name on my staging machine and production and it caused the same 'cannot find server'-error.

(Guess you shouldn't use synonyms that much anyway but it's useful in some migration scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was facing same issue with following ,

```
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("uspx_GetTemplate", connection);
```

but after adding square bracket to stored procedure name it get solved.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[uspx_GetTemplate]", connection);
```